# Android phone as secondary screen

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, display

I want to use my android phone (LG G3) as a second screen for my laptop. My laptop dual boots Linux(Xubuntu) and Windows(8.1), so an application that is running on either of those is fine.

## Requirements:

- Must work with android **PHONE**. Not tablet.
- Must support "extend" mode. (I mean [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBqE4.jpg)) (I don't know if Linux has it)
- Must be free. (No trial time or anything, just fully free)

## I don't care about:

- Whether it's wireless or wired, both options are OK. (I don't really care about lag or resolution)
- Whether it runs on Linux or Windows. (Not Mac!)

## Nice-to-have:

- If on Linux, an option to assign a specific workspace to the phone, and others stay on the laptop's screen. (From Xfce4, if that matters)

Also, I heard some stuff about Linux's X-servers, maybe that can make it simpler or something? Maybe an x-client for android phone?

**EDIT:**
Tried DimP's response [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/306741/503298), moving the mouse out of the screen works like expected, however dragging the window just changes it to another workspace... Tried doing both -south and -north so that xfce doesn't care about workspaces, but panels "block" the movement... And I think that there must be a better way...

Comment: [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28608/how-do-you-use-an-android-tablet-as-a-second-display) is a solution using a VNC server. I have not tried it myself.

Comment: @DimP It works and the mouse behaves like in "extend" mode, but I can't understand how to move a window to the other screen... I used http://askubuntu.com/a/306741/503298 answer.

Comment: Do you mind installing an alternative OS on your phone? (I don't have an idea, but just to know)

Comment: 3 and a half years late to the party. https://spacedesk.net/ is exactly what you wanted for Windows

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to take a look at **[spacedesk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ph.spacedesk.beta):**

- supports Windows (8.1 and 10; requires a Windows companion app)
- supports phone as well as tablet
- works with extended mode as well as mirror mode
- is listed as "free" (and comes without trackers)

For Linux, indeed an X-Server might be an option. Take a look at

- [XServer XSDL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=x.org.server)
- [X Server](https://f-droid.org/packages/au.com.darkside.xdemo/) (very light-weight!)

Not sure how they work as extension (to be dealt with the computer mouse directly), as I haven't tried that.